# How to save a file with dynamic value in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to save response xml-file with dynamic value using a variable.
I am passing a value through a variable which is got from CSV Data Set Config (e.g. `var = Abc123`).

I have mentioned the **filename prefix** as `D:\response\${var}` where `var` is my variable.

But the file is getting saved as `${var}.xml` itself, instead of `Abc123.xml.`

Please suggest if there is any way to save the file with dynamic value.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

We are speaking about [Save Responses to a file](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Save_Responses_to_a_file) listener, right?

So you have to either:

**1.** double back-slashes in Filename prefix field:

```
D:\\response\\${var}
```

because a single backslash in this case will be taken as 'escape' character and variable will be not expanded to its value;

or:

**2.** define `D:\response\` part elsewhere in the script as separate variable e.g. `${responsePath}` and replace `D:\response\` in Filename prefix field with this variable:

```
${responsePath}${var}
```

Both variants will work correctly but the 2nd one seems to be a bit more general.