# How to use Jmeter's 'Simple Data Writer' to store data in dynamic filenames

Tags: jmeter

Can anyone let me know how to use 'Simple Data Writer' in Jmeter to store data in dynamic file names?

I need to store request and response for each SOAP call processed from Jmeter in different files.
I want to pass the variable name 'ABC' used in the jmeter as the file name. It is expected to create a folder with the date and create the file with value in 'ABC' variable and store the data I selected in the 'configure'

The 'Filename' that I have set under 'Simple Data Writer' is as:

```
C:\XXX\JMeter\\${__time(dd-MMM-Y)}\\${ABC}.xml
```

This setting is only creating the folder correctly, but the file name is being created as `${ABC}.xml` instead of the value in ${ABC}

Also I see that the data is not being stored properly in xml format. Instead of populating < and > for XML Tags, `&lt;` and `&gt;` are being populated in the data respectively.

Sample below:

```
&lt;imp1:Name/&gt;
&lt;imp1:Pay&gt;515255413&lt;/imp1:Pay&gt;
&lt;imp1:CCLast&gt;6380&lt;/imp1:CCLast&gt;
&lt;imp1:CCType&gt;VISA&lt;/imp1:CCType&gt;
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Note: I am able to resolve the file name issue by using 'Save Responses to a file' as it indeed is able to fetch the variable values and create the files correctly. But this does not provide me the Request for the SOAP call as it displays only the response which does not solve my cause.

Comment: Why are you saving every request and response in a performance test? This is a very expensive operation to perform with several concurrent threads - disk usage on your jmeter machine will quickly become a bottleneck, thwarting you from effectively applying load on the application under test. You should consider saving req/response only under certain conditions like when an error occurs.

Comment: I am not doing a load test at the moment. It is required for some functional testing to be done for SOAP calls and so i would need to save those requests and responses. Is there any other way to get this information via JMeter? 
Also i observed that if i just use the time function, i can create separate files for each run. But as said that is not what i want. I want to pass a variable name.

Comment: There was a response provided for similar issue under the below thread. 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13470557/how-to-save-a-file-with-dynamic-value-in-jmeter?rq=1' . But it does not seem to work

Comment: The answer you linked uses the `Save responses to a file` listener. Your question is about `Simple data writer`. You should probably accept the answer below and raise a new question. Jmeter may not be the right tool to do functional testing. Have you considered using SoapUI? Even if you are using JMeter, it is better to have asserts determining if the expected results are returned instead of writing to file and verifying later.

Comment: I agree that the link posted is not correct. I have already tried SoapUI and it does not have the facilities available in Jmeter for parametrizing the XML tags. I already have Assertions in place for success or failure. Since we are using Jmeter for functional tests, it is important to store the request and responses unlike load testing.

Answer (score 1):

Jmeter Simple Data Writer does not do what you're looking for. The Simple Data Writer writes data, in CSV or XML format to a single file for an entire test. The data of each request/response is a separate line or XML block within the same file.

Since you're looking to write a new file per request/response, this is not possible with Simple Data Writer.

#### Variable in filename:

Looks like JMeter does not support using a variable for filename. (I'm unsure if this is by design or a bug) However properties works fine. You can convert the variable you want to use into a property using the `__setProperty` function and then use `${__P(propName)}` in the filename textbox.

Comment: We can write new file per request/response with Jmeter functions, but we are not able to send variables as file names in 'Simple Data Writer'

Comment: How are you able to generate a new file per req/resp? I tried putting the SDW both under the sampler scope and under the thread group scope. In both cases it generates only 1 log file with multiple entries. Also, using `__time` for either directory name or file name seems to work, but using `${variable}` is not working.

Comment: Btw, using a property as a filename `${__P(propFileName)}` works just fine.

Comment: Yes, it worked only for the time function for me. It was not working when variables were sent.. i will try the Property function and check.
Since it was not working for me, i had to write a beanshell program to get a new file per request by sending different variables. Also if i am using Simple Data Writer, the `< and >` are not getting populated correctly as explained in the original post. I tried the getsamplerdata() method you explained in the other thread (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30332350/where-is-the-request-for-a-soap-call-stored-in-jmeter) and it worked perfectly.

Comment: decode it with `__unescape`. see here: http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__unescapeHtml

Comment: Thanks, i get the point. But we can use it in java/bean script. How can we use it with Simple Data Writer?

Comment: you can try enabling ’sample_variables’ in jmeter or user properties, but I'm afraid the string will get re-encoded while writing to file.

Comment: I would like to see some example. I am fighting 1/2 of the day make simple data writter not hardcoded path.

Answer (score 0):

I used Jmeter 5.4.3 and simple data writer with adressing variable. The hint is that you can't directly use variable in the simple data writer filename. So if you use javascript function of variable like ${date}.jtl, you will receive the same hardcoded name with curly brackets.
**What you need to do is to add some symbols here before variable:**
**test results\res${date}.jtl**
In User defined variables I defined ${date} as ${__time(ddMMMyyyy_HHmm,)}