# Where is the request for a SOAP call stored in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to print the SOAP Request into a file using BeanShell as i had to do some verifications.

I am able to get the response for the SOAP call using `String response = prev.getResponseDataAsString();` which can be printed to the file.

Similarly what is the method that can be used to get the Request sent for SOAP call in Jmeter?

Note: I tried to use `SoapSampler.getxmldata()`. But it did not give me the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the SOAP request is submitted as a HTTP POST call, with xml content as POST body, `prev.getSamplerData()` will contain request information.

Example:
In beanshell post processor: `vars.put("requestData", prev.getSamplerData());`

Results in:

```
requestData=POST url

POST data:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
      ...
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: Awesome!! This is exactly what i was looking for in the API Docs as well. Can you please tell me which class of API is holding this method?

Comment: https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html#getSamplerData()

Comment: cool.. thanks alot... i have gone through that class, but did not check this one..

Answer (score 1):

If you use [SOAP/XML-RPC Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#SOAP/XML-RPC_Request) you can access it's XML body from [Beanshell PostProcessor](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) as:

```
String body = ctx.getCurrentSampler().getXmlData();
```

where `ctx` is a shorthand to [JmeterContext](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterContext.html) class

Comment: I am not able to get the Request SOAP message with ctx. Is there some problem with the code in BeanShell PostProcessor?
`f = new FileOutputStream(ResultDir, true); 
p = new PrintStream(f); 
String a = ctx.getCurrentSampler().getxmlData();
p.println(a);`

Comment: 1. Mind the capital "X" in `getXmlData();` 2. I would recommend closing streams like `p.close();` as leaving them open may lead to open handles lack

Comment: Lovely.. yes it did work.. Thanks for correcting..
and yes i have used p.close() and f.close() as well.

Comment: What would be the difference between prev and ctx in this case then? Both of them seems to have the same information within them.

Comment: Also, how do we know what are the methods that can be used with ctx.getCurrentSampler()? I see that you have used getXmlData() with it.

Comment: `prev` is for [SampleResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html), `ctx.getCurrentSampler` is for [Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/Sampler.html) which could be HTTP, JDBC, SOAP, SMTP, etc. If you're uncertain what exact "sampler" you're using you can get it's implementation as `log.info(ctx.getCurrentSampler.getClass().getName();` and look for available methods in the returned class JavaDoc